# printing enum variables and values

Tags: java, enums

I am trying to test `enum` out but I am currently having a bit of trouble. I want to be able to print out the values but I am not sure how to.

code:

```
class test2 {
    public enum games {
        COD (3, 49.99), CS (5, 29.99), HL2 (5, 29.99), HALO (5, 49.99);
        int rating;
        float cost;
        games(int rating, float cost) {
            this.rating = rating;
            this.cost = cost;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (games g : games.values()) {
            System.out.println(g +" " + g.rating + " " + g.cost);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just converted your `float` to `double` and it works fine.

Comment: Do I need to sound the usual advice about not using `float` or `double` to store amounts of money?

Comment: You should use `BigDecimal` to store currency, and you should probably implement `toString()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must to replace that

```
float
```

with

```
double
```

And execute your code :)

Answer (score 2):

Your calls to the enum constructor use the wrong type for the field `cost` as defined.

You can correct this by changing the field type to `double` or by passing floats in the calls, i.e., either change

```
    float cost;
    games(int rating, float cost) {
```

to

```
    double cost;
    games(int rating, double cost) {
```

or change

```
    COD (3, 49.99), CS (5, 29.99), HL2 (5, 29.99), HALO (5, 49.99);
```

to

```
    COD (3, 49.99f), CS (5, 29.99f), HL2 (5, 29.99f), HALO (5, 49.99f);
```

With either change, your code runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
COD (3, 49.99f), CS (5, 29.99f), HL2 (5, 29.99f), HALO (5, 49.99f);
```

default for floating point in java is double ;-)